# Tabbar replace view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I want to replace view controller from tabbar controller for some specific conditions. Here is my code.

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

   NSInteger selectIndex=[tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

 if (selectIndex==2) {

    UserObject * user=[[SharedClass sharedInstance] getUser];
    if (user.license_no.length>0 && user.insurance_no.length>0) {

        OfferRideVC *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OfferRideVC"];

        NSMutableArray *allviews=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[tabBarController viewControllers]];
        [allviews removeObjectAtIndex:selectIndex];
        [allviews insertObject:vc atIndex:selectIndex];
        [tabBarController setViewControllers:allviews];

      }


  }

  return YES;
}
```

But my app crashes with this error.
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected.'

Can anyone have some idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because you are still returning **YES** at the end of the function, so TabBar tries to select viewController which is now not in its ViewControllers list.

Return **NO** from your if case,

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

   NSInteger selectIndex=[tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

 if (selectIndex==2) {

    UserObject * user=[[SharedClass sharedInstance] getUser];
    if (user.license_no.length>0 && user.insurance_no.length>0) {

        OfferRideVC *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OfferRideVC"];

        NSMutableArray *allviews=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[tabBarController viewControllers]];
        [allviews removeObjectAtIndex:selectIndex];
        [allviews insertObject:vc atIndex:selectIndex];
        [tabBarController setViewControllers:allviews];

        // ViewControllers changed, return NO
        return NO;
      }


  }

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing in didSelectViewController delegate and it works fine. Thanks.